# Internationalization of models in Django applications

Tags: python, django, django-models, localization, internationalization

My application will be available in two languages: english and german. The application will have a couple of XType objects with a description field. How can I translate the description field of XType? Does Django provide support for this or I will have to use another Django application?

```
class XType(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class X(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(XType)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not provide direct support of model field translations.

You have to find a way to deal with it either within Django or via plugable applications (like posted already django-easymode or check http://blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/06/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django.html).

If you want to deal within your app with it you might want to try something like saving one instance per language and then filter accordingly when retrieving data:

```
class XType(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Depends of course a lot on your project needs.

Comment: I have tried the translation using modeltranslation. Followed the steps and it works. The field to be translated can be changed from admin.

Answer (score 0):

[django-easymode](http://packages.python.org/django-easymode/index.html) includes the [@i18n decorator](http://packages.python.org/django-easymode/i18n/index.html), which may solve your case:

> At times it becomes a requirement to
>   translate models. Django supports
>   internationalization of static text in
>   templates and code by means of
>   gettext. For translation of models -
>   dynamic data - easymode offers simple
>   decorators to enable internationalized
>   model fields and localized admin
>   classes.