# How can I use model like a custom field

Tags: django, django-models

Recently I've been developing a Django website, which includes the owner being able to add content with descriptions etc.

The problem I'm having is: How can I make the fields support multiple languages? (3 in this case)

The approach I tried was: Creating a model with 3 text fields, have my content model take that model as a foreign key. This sort of works, but now I would have to create all the descriptions first, separately, before creating the actual object it is being used by. This is, in my opinion, a bad idea.

What I would like to be able to do, is to have 3 text fields in the model which is actually using those 3 text fields' admin page, but without actually having 3 text fields in that model.

Using inlines would work, but I'd have to make my multilanguage textfield model have a foreign key to my content model, instead of the other way. This would mean the multilanguage model works for only other model type.

So, to clear the question up:

- How can I have a TextField and a CharField support multiple languages?
- How can I show the ForeignKey's target model's creation widget in it's owner's admin page?
- How can I use inlines, without locking the inline to just one model type?
- How can I make a model act like a field?
- How can I write a custom TextField?

Answering any of those will be enough for me to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is too many questions and the docs is at your reach... I'll just answer the easiest one you should have search for by yourself.

- How can I have a TextField and a CharField support multiple languages?

You should have a look to i18n [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/)

- How can I write a custom TextField?

Have a look to [custom Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/)

Comment: And also, for your models, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644770/internationalization-of-models-in-django-applications

Comment: i18n doesn't seem to be supported by Django versions over 1.3, and I'm using 1.6

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is still supported : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/


Still, I tried once that module and it was pretty efficient 
: https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation


Hope this helps.